# is there a way to merge properties in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I wonder if someone has been in similar situation:

I currently have 2 Google Analytics properties.

1. Native AOS/iOS app that is integrated with Firebase
2. Website that is integrated with tag manager

As the website was developed later than the app, we ended up creating separate properties on GA, however, now the website will only be available to traffic from inside the app (the website will be shown in a WebView), so it makes sense to merge the all data should be attributed to the users from the App property.

On the website configuration on GTM, I created a base pixel that fires on all pages with the measurement ID of the website. I noticed that there is no measurement id on the app settings peoperty, but a firebase id, so I am not sure how to proceed.
Is the only solution to this case is to integrate the firebase events to the website?

Answer (score 0):

No, you're mixing up data streams with properties. Also, I assume we're talking here about GA4 and not GAUA since you used the term `measurement id` rather than `property id`.

Go to your GA4 property where the firebase traffic is. Go to Admin. Go to the `Data Streams` under the Property section of the admin panel. You should see there your Firebase streams. Make a new one, for web. Copy Web's measurement id, paste it in GTM's config tag. Good, publish. Now you have your webview tracking flowing into the same property your firebase is flowing to.

There's one caveat to watch out for. The app may not pass your client id and session id into the webview. You may need to ask the devs to pass those in query params or cookies and then remap them properly with GTM. Just to make sure your data is not only in one property, but also makes sense session-wise and user-wise.

As for the old web data, it shouldn't be important. If it's still important to merge old web data with the app data, well, you can't merge it in GA. You will have to merge it down the ETL pipe somewhere. BQ would be a fitting place to merge, but it's up to whoever does the ETL.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your help!  

Regarding passing client id and session id, I don't want to take advantage of your kindness, but could this be done via url parameters (www.blablabla.com?session_id=123&client_id+abc), or perhaps via datalayer variable? After that, I wonde if I should pass the ids on "Fields to set", "User Properties" or "Tag Metadata" in the base pixel on GTM.

Comment: So the app developers can use different technologies to make a web view. From there, it depends whether they can make it a dataLayer variable. Ask the devs. If both platforms are ok with pushing a DLE, then go with DLE, but both should be able to push parameters too. The tricky part for them is to get those from the SDK, especially the session id. But let them work with that. If they can't get the sid, there are ways to mitigate.